# Using WSUS to download patches/updates

Tags: windows-server-2008, wsus

Currently, I have WSUS(service pack 2) installed on Windows Server 2008 R2. The situation is, I do not know how to get updates from the internet using WSUS. Is there a guide reference in setting up the WSUS software to allow updates to be downloaded to the server computer? After the updates are downloaded using WSUS, there is a downstream WSUS server to pull the updates from the upstream WSUS server which is the one which I am facing an issue with.

Answer (score 2):

Start with downloading the appropriate version for your server [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=a206ae20-2695-436c-9578-3403a7d46e40&displaylang=en). While you are installing this on your server, it will ask you for the products, languages, ... and types (critical, optional, ...) you want to update. I usually select them all because they aren't installed until you approve them.

Once that is over, you can start configuring the clients. Use the Group Policy Management Console to create a new policy and link it to the an Organizational Unit. Then edit it and browse to Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update. Here you’ll need to edit a few policies:

- Configure Automatic Updates: Enable
- Specify intranet Microsoft update service location: Enable (and give the address to your SWUS server)
- No Auto-restart with logged on users for scheduled automatic updates: Enable (Your users will hate you if you don't enable this, but it's optional)

That should get you up and running, if you want, you could divide the computers in groups and make different rules for applying patches. You might also want to create a few rules to allow certain patches to go thru automatically. You do not wan't to approve them all by hand.